# Why for some images $_FILES['image_name']['size'] showing blank values or 0 instead of the size of file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file, file-upload, image-uploading

I've following form for uploading image to the server:

```
<form id="request_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="file" name="student_image" id="student_image" accept="image/*" capture/>                  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I tried to print the data contained in `$_FILES` array for few image files I'm only getting File name other fields are either blank or contains 0 value. I'm not understanding why this is happening.

Following is one sample out put of `$_FILES` I got after `print_r($_FILES);` array for such image:

```
Array
(
    [student_image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Page After Login.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

The actual size on disk of file Page After Login.jpg is **2.3 MB**

For other images it's working properly.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: You have an upload error - see the [error] element. Error codes are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). In this case your uploaded file exceeds the maximum upload size set for your installation of PHP.

Comment: @HoboSapiens:Thanks for spotting the error. Can you please tell me how should I override this setting from php.ini. I can't access the php.ini file on server but for this specific program I want to increase the upload limit. How should I?

Comment: You need to edit `php.ini`. The details can be found on the manual pages I linked to.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: I've got two php.ini files on my server one is at location /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and the other is at location /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. So which one needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can see there was an error during upload. The docs say

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Use a smaller file, or up the size limit in your config.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error. Can you please tell me how should I override this setting from php.ini. I can't access the php.ini file on server but for this specific program I want to increase the upload limit. How should I do this?

Comment: Contact your sysadmin or hosting company to change the limit.

Comment: I've got two php.ini files on my server one is at location /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and the other is at location /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. So which one needs to be changed?

Comment: The one under apache2, usually that's the one used by the webserver's php process.

Comment: Can I achieve this with ini_set() function?

Answer (score 0):

the file is not get uploaded that's why tmp_name variable value is blank.and for successful upload there is a need of value in this varialbe.just check the upload_max_filesize in your **php.ini** file and restart your web server after change that variable.
By using this function in your script at the top, u can change that varialbe in `php.ini`

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");
```

here 300M menans you can upload a file uplto size of 300 MB.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error. Can you please tell me how should I override this setting from php.ini. I can't access the php.ini file on server but for this specific program I want to increase the upload limit. How should I do this?